# How to hide a div from angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-controller

I have a div in my html like

```
<div class="row" ng-show="loginCtrl.showTouchID" >
    <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button type="button" class="col-xs-12 btn btn-touch-id" data-ng-click="#">
                        TouchID Login
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now need to check in my controller contructor that whether the device support touch id if it is show the div or else not

```
  window.plugins.touchid.isAvailable(
            function (msg) {
                navigator.notification.alert('Touch id  supported: ' + msg);
                loginCtrl.showTouchID=true;


            }, function (msg) {
                navigator.notification.alert('Touch id not supported: ' + msg);
                loginCtrl.showTouchID=false;

            });
```

But this doesnt work well,Can anyone correct me

Below my login controller

```
  angular.module('heritage').controller('LoginCtrl', LoginCtrl);
    LoginCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$rootScope', '$state', '$window', 'UserService', 'ServiceHelper', '$stateParams'];

    /**
     * Construct the controller.
     * @param $rootScope the root scope
     * @param $state the state object
     * @param $window the window object
     * @param UserService the user service
     * @returns the controller object
     */
    function LoginCtrl($scope,$rootScope, $state, $window, UserService, ServiceHelper, $stateParams) {
```

Comment: Make sure that this div is within the ng-controller element. Also, use $scope.loginCtrl.showTouchID instead of loginCtrl.showTouchID to access this variable in the view. Share the loginCtrl code also. It is not clear whether you are using $scope or not anywhere.

Comment: doesnt woked i have updated my question, the alerts are invoked but no change in div

Comment: Can you set up a demo fiddle?

Comment: Seems as u told above the issue with scope only i can hide/show div by setting loginCtrl.showTouchID=false; outside  window.plugins.touchid.isAvailable methode but inside this not working

Comment: How could i access hideTouchId  inside the window.plugins.touchid.isAvailable method? i tried using $scope.loginCtrl.hideTouchId=true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deLt4qgg/1/):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="dummy">
    <div class="row" ng-show="loginCtrl.showTouchID">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="button" class="col-xs-12 btn btn-touch-id" data-ng-click="setTouch('hello')">TouchID Login</button>
        </div>
        <p>{{loginCtrl.showTouchID}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('dummy', function ($scope) {
    $scope.loginCtrl = {showTouchID: true};

    $scope.setTouch = function (msg) {
        if ($scope.loginCtrl.showTouchID) {
            alert('Touch id not supported: ' + msg);
            $scope.loginCtrl.showTouchID = false;
        } else {
            alert('Touch id supported: ' + msg);
            $scope.loginCtrl.showTouchID = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How could i access hideTouchId inside the window.plugins.touchid.isAvailable method? i tried using $scope.loginCtrl.hideTouchId=true; but doesnt work

Comment: inject `$window` in the controller and use it as `$window.plugins.touchid.isAvailable`

Comment: $window.plugins.touchid.isAvailable this method is working fine please look my controller i have inject $window in the controller and inside the alerts are fired also but $scope.loginCtrl.showTouchID = true; doesnt make any changes to my dom

Comment: But if i put loginCtrl.showTouchID outside the method for testing working seems that is not accessible inside that method how can i fix this

Comment: please update the answer with your own JSFiddle, it's not easy without looking at it

Comment: this are using cordova plugins ( 
$window.plugins.touchid.isAvailable)

Comment: Did you define `$scope.loginCtrl = {}`?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `$scope` to your function (if it is external) and change `$scope` variables there.

```
  window.plugins.touchid.isAvailable($scope
            function (msg) {
                navigator.notification.alert('Touch id  supported: ' + msg);
                $scope.showTouchID=true;


            }, function (msg) {
                navigator.notification.alert('Touch id not supported: ' + msg);
                $scope.showTouchID=false;

            });
```